# Excel: remove text after the first non allowable character

Tags: excel

I wish to remove text from a string from the first non-allowable character on. I have gotten so far, but now im stuck.

Real Example:

The cells value is:
transactions_Label}" showEffect="{showView}" width="100%" height="100%" transactionScreen="true" />

I want the only allowable characters to be 0-9 a-z and underscore _:

The result would be:
transactions_Label

Thanks if you can help

Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont like answering my own question, but this is what I used in VBA:

```
Sub TrimRight()

    mycolumn = "E" 'Change to suit

    Dim MyRange, MyRange1 As Range

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, mycolumn).End(xlUp).Row

    Set MyRange = Range(mycolumn & "1:" & mycolumn & LastRow)

    For Each c In MyRange
        For X = 1 To Len(c.Value)
            If Mid(c.Value, X, 1) Like "[!0-9A-Za-z_]" Then
                c.Value = Left(c.Value, X - 1)
                Exit For
            End If
         Next
    Next

End Sub
```